# What was the Crew Dragon reentry mass for the mission that landed August 2, 2020?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2

What was the Crew Dragon reentry and touchdown mass for the mission that landed August 2, 2020?

(I found that Soyuz Descent Module has a reentry mass of 2850 kg.)
See: http://www.braeunig.us/space/specs/soyuz.htm

I just want to compare the two landing modules.

Comment: I think they mentioned the mass at undocking was 24,000 lbs (includes trunk)

Comment: Wikipedia notes the mass at "NASA live stream commentators made note of capsule mass with trunk of 27000lbs and 21000lbs without the trunk". This statement does not include a timestamped link; though that would probably be somewhat easy to find as this was mentioned on the stream within 20 minutes of the undocking occuring.

Answer (score 1):

NASA says:

> After trunk separation and the deorbit burn are complete, **the Crew Dragon capsule weighs approximately 21,200 pounds [~9600 kg]**.

From [Top 10 Things to Know for NASA’s SpaceX Demo-2 Return](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/top-10-things-to-know-for-nasa-s-spacex-demo-2-return), item #4.